# Installed Ubuntu 15.10 after Windows 10 - boots straight to Ubuntu

Tags: grub2, windows-10

I installed Windows 10 on a 60GB SSD (/dev/sdc in Ubuntu) in my computer, then installed Ubuntu 15.10 on a 120GB SSD (/dev/sda in Ubuntu) in my computer. GRUB boots straight into Ubuntu. When I hold shift upon startup and see GRUB, there is no Windows 10 entry.

I'd like the GRUB menu to show every time, and I'd like a Windows 10 entry in GRUB that'll boot into it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 0):

You should try [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```